# failed to load or display dynamically a list view using Trigger.io and JQuery mobile on emulator Android

Tags: php, html, android-emulator, trigger.io, jquery-mobile-listview

I created an application that display dynamically a list view from Data Base 
I used **HTML5 JQuery Mobile** and **PHP** and running it with **Trigger.io** on emulator Android
so it works good on browsers and display the list contains an image and text..

so here's so codes 
the html5

```
<div data-role="page" id="restaurant_favoris" data-theme="c" >
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content-list">
        <ul  data-role="listview">
            <?php render('resto') ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the php call a service that iterate a Table and display

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/img/list/album-k.jpg" />
        <h3>Name  <?php echo $favoritrestaurant->name?></h3>
        <p>nombre de points est <?php echo $favoritrestaurant-> nombre_points?></p>
    </a>
</li>
```

like I said it works on browsers and no things to display on emulator android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing a Forge-Run-Android?

That will not work trying to run PHP on Android.

You will need to create a service on your web server where your database resides and call that service with javascript, ideally returning the data in something like JSON. Call it with forge.request.ajax and process the results similarly to how your are with PHP, just do it with javascript.

See Docs here:
https://trigger.io/modules/request/current/docs/index.html#forgerequestajaxoptions

Comment: sorry for late, thanks that's my last choice, so i implement the web service but i have a problem with display, it retrieve data from WS but display indifined for all list item

Comment: Can you post your WS data output and the code you're using to display it? Sounds like your syntax is wrong, but it's hard to say without seeing what data you're working with and how you're trying to display it.

Comment: Hi, I've changed my code, the HTML call a JS not a php code, then the  JS call a WS. finally it works. if you don't understand what i mean, i'll post the code, thanks.